# Data is "out of date" and won't refresh in Tableau Server

Tags: refresh, tableau-api

I have a project that connects to multiple different PostGres databases via extracts. Uploading the projects to our company Tableau server is no problem, but the scheduled refreshes almost always fail, even though I have embedded all of the passwords when publishing the project. One single time it worked, but I don't know why. I have tried letting them refresh when I'm logged into my company's VPN as well as having the databases connected and open in PostGres; also, I've tried letting them refresh when away from my computer. Either way, it's the same sad story. Can anybody explain what is going on?

Here is an example of the error I get on the Tableau server page:

Screen Shot 2018-07-24 at 1.30.00 PM.png
 [image: Tableau server error message]

From here, I click "Connection Details" to edit the connections in the Data Sources page of the project, and I see this:

Screen Shot 2018-07-24 at 1.40.39 PM.png
 [image: Tableau server > my project > "Data Sources" tab > "Actions: Edit Connection"]

(The server port in this example is "-------" because this particular source connects two different PG databases in a join, but I have some other sources with just one connection, and the port # is shown.) Everything looks fine to me, so I don't know what to do.

Thank you!!!

P.s. I can't post any packaged workbooks because the data contains sensitive company information.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 'localhost', use the FQDN or ip address.  That should work...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but connected to Oracle, seeing the server logs I came to these links ([link 1](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-ora-01843-not-a-valid-month-refreshing-data-source-extract) and [link 2](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-ora-01843-calculated-field)). In short, they talk about a conversion problem with date-type data. In my case I changed the query "cast" to "to_date", I raised the project again and I did not have any more problems.

I recommend you get to the server logs

regards